# Customized humanoid blender rig is getting some issue with unity avatar

Tags: unity, blender, rigging, avatar

TLDR;
After some thought, I think what my actual issue is that the exported rig from blender somehow isn't satisfying the unity avatar. I did add some extra bones, and still planning to add more in the future, but I don't think that should cause the issue. I just added extra arms, that's it. For some reason, the neck is on a different branch compared to the rest of the rig.

---

So I'm trying to make a unity library work that needs a humanoid rig, but I don't want to make a true humanoid rig. On my use case, I don't need the face because I mostly only need shapekey/blendshape for the face movements.

I tried a few things like removing bones one by one and just keeping the "head" bone, but blender doesn't like it because it somehow needs every single bone on the face to generate the rig if you want to add a real head. Just to investigate, I renamed the bones so I know what they represent, and I think I'm near an answer, but the hindering problem is kinda stupid.

[image]

So this is what unity is complaining about. All the UX knowledge of the world, and we have this. If you can't read what it says, it says "Neck Transform 'DEF-neck.low' is not a child of Spine Transform 'ORG-chest'". Which is so confusing, because this what my rig setup is.

[image]

UPDATE:
I did some additional testing and was able to fix the head, but caused an error with the body.

[image]

And the error this time is something weird again.

[image]

Basically, the error is saying that the shoulder isn't a child of the chest, which is wrong btw.

Here's the bone hierarchy in unity
[image]

Also, I realized that that avatar ui is misleading, making debugging this issue very confusing. And, maybe a blender issue, but the bone hierarchy isn't exported how it should be. This is what the bone hierarchy looks like on blender

[image]

UPDATE#2

I reexported and reimported the fbx just for testing, and remember that the mapping was different to what I previously have. What I did is put the bone with the same name as the bone mapping and that's when the issues appeared.

Here's what the initial mapping looks like.

[image]

Confusing, right? Chest for spine?

So what I did is match the bones to the mapping just to try stuff. And I think I fixed the body now, but now I have a weird dilemma. Which I'm thinking might be a blender issue.

[image]

Now, only the head have an error. But the problem is, it doesn't look to be fixable. Because, with the exported bone hierarchy from blender, the "neck" is somehow on a different branch of the hierarchy compared to the rest of the rig.

Comment: You mixed ORG and DEF again. You're using ORG for the chest but DEF for the neck.

Comment: But the shoulders are connected to the ORG chest, so that's why I used that for the chest rather than the DEF

Comment: You need to arrange your rig so that the neck and shoulder bones are not in completely separate sub-trees like this.

Comment: It is. But the exported one is the one that separated them for some reason. Check that blender screenshot I added. That rig is just the default blender rig without the face, with extra stuff. But it's not the cause of the error, I feel.

Comment: It seems to me that what you really want to ask is "How to export rig from Blender so neck and shoulder bones are in the same transform tree?" - detailing how you've created the current non-working version so folks can spot the step you need to fix.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure. Because from experience, that seems to be what have been blender has been exporting before. I'll update this question to see if that helps to get answers